# Multiple tourist visa short period Indonesia

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, indonesia, dutch-citizens

I will be travelling a lot out and in Indonesia for tourist purposes in a short period of time.

For example the 5th of December I will be leaving for Thailand and returning on the 10th, but already leaving for Malaysia on the 14th and returning on the 17th.

I am returning to Indonesia each time because I am travelling with my partner who has obligations in Indonesia.

This all will be done with the 30 day visa exemption, will the Indonesian immigration make a problem out of this?

FYI:
I am dutch and my partner is Indonesian

Comment: It's hard to be 100% certain, but it's unlikely you'll have any problems. There's no rules limiting 30-day entries, and Indonesian immigration is generally relaxed -- they actually want visitors. Entry to Thailand is less certain, if you travel there often.

Comment: To add information to your existing question, please use the "edit" link immediately below it; please don't do it by posting an entirely new question.